# Singapore Airlines seat selection after online booking

Tags: seating, check-in

I read some similar questions (e.g. [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/104858/can-i-refuse-to-choose-seats-with-additional-cost-at-check-in-time)), but they concern European airlines that have to act under European laws, Singapore Airlines probably doesn't.

I booked a flight from FRA to SIN (and further on, 4 legs in total back and forth). For all flights but the one mentioned, there were enough seats to select online one that wouldn't cost me any extra money. For the FRA - SIN flight there were only seats left they would charge me extra.

Obviously I don't have to select a seat now before checking in prior to my flight.

a) Will I have to when checking in online?

b) If not, will I probably just get any seat that is unoccupied at the time of checking in at the counter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Singapore Airlines seems to reserve a large number of seats further forward in the aircraft, which are not available for selection at booking time. When you check in, you will be able to select a seat. On the flights where you have already been able to select a seat, you will be able to switch to a more desirable seat if you wish. Check in as early as you can (48 hours before the flight), to ensure a good selection of seats. If you don't check in online, you will still be allocated a seat, but it probably won't be a good one.

This answer is from my own experience on Singapore  Airlines.